# How to get static part of label to show up only when textbox entered

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is  a little bit hard to explain so bear with me. I have measurements that appear on the screen after the user inputs them into the textbox provided. Right now, I have it so the number only shows up as it's being entered, which is great. The only thing is, the unit (cm, mm..) stays on the canvas permanently and I want that to only show up when the numbers are entered as well. I hope that makes sense.

The textbox code:

```
<TreeViewItem Grid.Row="1" FontSize="12" Header="Width"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding xcoord, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="x" Height="20" Width="40" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
<TreeViewItem Grid.Row="2" FontSize="12" Header="Height"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding ycoord, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="y" Height="20" Width="40" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

The label code:

```
<!--height label appears on screen when value is entered-->
<Label Foreground="SteelBlue" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="40" Background="Transparent" x:Name="label2"  FontSize="16" Width="60"  Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=y}" ContentStringFormat=" {0} mm" Canvas.Left="527" Canvas.Top="162" RenderTransformOrigin="1.045,-0.141" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Label>

<!--width label appears on screen when a value is entered-->
<Label Foreground="SteelBlue" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="40" Background="Transparent" x:Name="label1"  FontSize="16" Width="160"  Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=x}" ContentStringFormat=" {0} mm" Canvas.Left="220" Canvas.Top="382" RenderTransformOrigin="1.045,-0.141" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an IValueConverter, with which you can convert a value to any kind of output and display that. In your example it would look like this:

```
public class UnitValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string text = value as string;
        string unit = parameter as string;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            return $"{text}{unit}";
        }
        else
        {
            return text;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can then use this IValueConverter in your XAML-Code like [this](https://www.dotnetforall.com/wpf-using-ivalueconverter-code-example/). As the ConverterParameter you need to pass the unit string.